# Pass the third value from Datagridview to textbox, after pass two value to Select row

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms

How can I display the value of the third column of the Datagridview in Textbox,
pass to the value of the first and second columns from Textboxes

| Name | City | Age |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Jack | LA | 38 |
| Mark | NY | 25 |
| Vicky | NY | 31 |

when I pass the jack and LA
select the row and show the 38 in Textbox

Comment: There are numerous ways to do what you describe and a lot will depend on how the code fills the grid with data. Does the grid use a `DataSource`? This would simplify things. However, it is a guess as to how this is currently done. What have you tried?

Comment: It may help you if you take the SO [tour] to see how it works along with some helpful links to help you get an answer… [help], [help/on-topic], [help/dont-ask], [help/behavior] .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reproduce your problem.

UI page：

[image]

After clicking the button to add data, if only one value is entered in the text box, the age cannot be queried.

[image]

Enter the values of the two text boxes and click the show button to successfully query the age.

[image]

The specific logic is: click the add and button2 buttons to fill in the data, and then enter the value of the text box and click the show button to query the age.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int index = this.dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
        this.dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[0].Value = "jack";
        this.dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[1].Value = "LA";
        this.dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[2].Value = "38";
        this.dataGridView1.Rows[1].Cells[0].Value = "Mark";
        this.dataGridView1.Rows[1].Cells[1].Value = "NY";
        this.dataGridView1.Rows[1].Cells[2].Value = "25";
     
    }

    private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int index = this.dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
        this.dataGridView1.Rows[index].Cells[0].Value = "Vicky";
        this.dataGridView1.Rows[index].Cells[1].Value = "NY";
        this.dataGridView1.Rows[index].Cells[2].Value = "31";
    }

    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       
        if (this.textBox2.Text.Equals("") || this.textBox3.Text.Equals(""))
        {
            return;
        }
        // Linq fuzzy query
        IEnumerable<DataGridViewRow> enumerableList = this.dataGridView1.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>();
        List<DataGridViewRow> list = (from item in enumerableList
                                      where item.Cells[0].Value.ToString().IndexOf(this.textBox2.Text) >= 0
                                      select item).ToList();

       
        List<DataGridViewRow> list1 = (from item in enumerableList
                                      where item.Cells[1].Value.ToString().IndexOf(this.textBox3.Text) >= 0
                                      select item).ToList();
       
        if (list.Count > 0 && list1.Count > 0 )
        {
           
            int matchedRowIndex = list[0].Index;
            
            textBox1.Text = this.dataGridView1.Rows[matchedRowIndex].Cells[2].Value.ToString();
        }


    }
}
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: thanks , my idea is select row where the column1 and columon2 equal the data, it like the search

Comment: @Vicky_Smaith  Hello,Did you mean: Enter the city and name from the text box to find out the age.

Comment: Yes, 1-you pass the two value from textboxs 2- Select the row when found, it Automatically 3- show the result into textbox